# What's the best Dictionary for intermediates?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for some fine English dictionaries for intermediate use.
Hope someone can share some dictionaries which provides definitions that easy to comprehend.

Comment: The trouble is that a situation requiring an advanced treatment (even a stipulative, outside-OED-scope and even outside-ELU-scope definition) can easily arise. But 'TheFreeDictionary' site gives access to 3 very good dictionaries.

Comment: Collins is very good for English language learners as its definitions are complete sentences. For example, compare its definition of "superstitious" https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/superstitious ...

Comment: ... with those listed by TheFreeDictionary: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/superstitious

Comment: Most online dictionaries are geared towards everyday common use. They only give one or two primary meanings with little nuance, which is what you want as an intermediate learner. Only the OED (which is behind a paywall) might be overwhelming to an intermediate learner, not because it is arcane or difficult to navigate, but because it just has a huge amount of data to consume on single words and needs a lot of fluency already to read all that material -before- you begin to judge the nuance of the words. If you're looking for a good intermediate paper dictionary... wow, I'm sure those exist but

Comment: I agree with @Shoe about Collins. They've got several series out, based on real corpora of real usage. Don't know which dictionary would be best, but they're all good.

Comment: You may want to ask this question on [ell.SE] or [languagelearning.se] where there are more people who know about teaching English to non-native speakers.